# No Diagrama de Classes qual a diferença entre Classes de Fronteira, Entidade e Controle?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, uml

Comecei a fazer a especificação de um projeto em UML e na ferramenta que estou usando tem Classes de Fronteira, Classes de Entidade e Classes de Controle pra fazer os Diagramas de Classes e Diagramas de Sequências, qual a diferença entre esses tipos de classes na hora de fazer a especificação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Classe de Entidade**: Modela objetos que o comportamento e informação devem ser armazenados.

**Classe de Fronteira (ou Interface)**: Modela a interação entre o ambiente do 
sistema e suas operações.

**Classe de Controle**: Modela o comportamento de controle especifico para uma ou mais casos de uso.

Referências:

- [Análise orientada a objetos](http://www.devmedia.com.br/artigo-engenharia-de-software-2-analise-orientada-a-objetos/9150)
- [Tipos de classes](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~amendes/GlossarioUML/glossario/conteudo/classe/tipos_de_classe.htm)
- [Diagrama de classes](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/3025/uml/diagrama-de-classes?trace=1519021197&source=single)

Comment: obrigado, era exatamente o que procurava

Answer (score 0):

### Estereótipo das Classes

Os tipos de classes do nosso modelo é um tema que que não abordamos com frequência no nosso dia a dia de DEVs, pois a maioria dos diagramas de classes que modelamos ou que visualizamos, são focamos na identificação das Classes de Domínio, aquelas que modelam objetos associados ao domínio do problema (regra de negócio).

E geralmente não avançamos para a identificação das classes de projeto, deixando de identificar elementos de Controle e Fronteira nos modelos de análise. Por isso, cabe um registro mais detalhado aqui para futuras referências..

Podemos utilizar os ícones abaixo para representar, respectivamente, classes de Fronteira, Controle e Entidade.

[image: Representação conceitual]

### Entity (Entidade)

representam abstrações de conceitos do mundo real, modelam informações e são essenciais para suportar funcionalidades do sistema.
São independentes da aplicação e geralmente pertencentes ao domínio do problema que está sendo modelado.
São persistentes, ou seja, correspondem a entidades de banco de dados.
Pensando em modelos de implementação, uma classe de entidade é essencialmente um wrapper de objeto para uma tabela de banco de dados. Os atributos de uma entidade são transformados em colunas da tabela.

*Exemplos:*

- Domínio Educacional: aluno, curso, turma, disciplina, docente, etc.
- Domínio Clínica médica: médico, paciente, exame, diagnóstico, etc.
- Domínio Jurídico: advogado, juiz, processo, julgamento, etc.

[image: Classe usuário]

### Boundary (Fronteira ou Interface)

Representam objetos que realizam a comunicação entre o sistema e o mundo externo (outros sistemas, atores, etc).
Modelam as interfaces do sistema com o ambiente externo.
São dependentes do ambiente do sistema.

Podemos separá-las por tipos:

- Classes de interface com o usuário
- Classes de interface com sistemas: responsáveis pela comunicação com outros sistemas
- Classes de interface dispositivos: Disponibilizam interface de comunicação com dispositivos como sensores e câmeras e são responsáveis por capturar os eventos externos gerados por estes atores, e que são relevantes para o sistema.

*Exemplos:*

- Administradora de cartão, Sistema de ponto, etc.
- Catraca, sensor de presença, etc.

[image: Diagrama de classes de fronteira]

Fonte: Harco Leslie (researchgate)

### Control

Coordenam o comportamento no sistema controlando a execução de processos, fluxos e orquestram outras classes.
Cria, ativa, anula e controla a concorrência aos objetos controlados.

Em casos de uso mais simples, como manipulações de informações armazenadas (CRUD), o sistema entrega a funcionalidade sem a necessidade de classes de controle, usando apenas classes de entidade e de fronteira.
Porém, casos de uso mais complexos, como a criação de uma campanha de marketing ou o fechamento de um pedido, requerem uma ou mais classes de controle para coordenar o comportamento dos objetos que cooperam para a execução do caso de uso.

Classes de controle geralmente são criadas quando o sistema executa um caso de uso e seu ciclo de vida tem duração até que o caso de uso seja concluído.

Este tipo de objeto facilita o desacoplamento entre objetos de entidade e de fronteira tornando o sistema mais tolerante a mudanças.
Também desacoplam o comportamento específico dos casos de uso das classes de entidade, tornando-as assim mais reutilizáveis.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: CIN - UFPE

### Conclusão

Quando avançamos na análise para a identificação das classes de projeto,
uma visualização mas detalhada salta aos olhos dos analistas, facilitando a comunicação
e o entendimento dos artefatos de sistema que serão desenvolvidos e como eles se comunicam.

Para finalizar, abaixo temos um exemplo de comunicação entre os vários tipos de classes de um projeto: entidade, fronteira e controle, que ajuda a identificar como estes objetos colaboram:

[image: Diagrama de classes]

fonte: (Fu-Ming Lee - cyut.edu.tw)

### Referências

1. [Find Classes from Use-Case Behavior](https://www.cyut.edu.tw/%7Efmlee/course/oosaad/06Suca-1.html)
2. [Modelagem de Sistemas com UML (parte 2) - URFJ](https://www.inf.ufpr.br/lmperes/2017_2/ci167/uml/uml_parte2_coppe.pdf)
3. [UML - Tipos de classes - Prof Rosenclever](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llAen63GCYk)
4. [Modelo de classes de especificação - Perspectiva de Projeto](https://www.inf.ufpr.br/silvia/ES/UML/pdf/DiagClassesIIAL.pdf)